# Cache/Memory size recommended for memcached?

Tags: memcached

Hi so I want to know what's the recommended cache or memory size for memcached? I'm running a drupal site on AwS Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a very subjective question as it depends on what you are caching and how big your data is. That you will have to figure out yourself. 
After you do that you should know that on average you get a 60 to 70% utilization on memcache.

So if you are planning to cache around 6GB of data then its good to allocate 10GB to Memcache.

You can take a look [here](http://www.mikeperham.com/2009/06/22/slabs-pages-chunks-and-memcached/) to see how memcache works. This will explain why it is not possible to fully utilize memcache